# Customizing the theorem environment

Tags: amsmath, theorems

I need to use a customized for of theorem environment in Latex. I put the code here. However, I am not sure what is the standard way to also change the numbering to the font as the title of the theorem is changed.

```
\documentclass[journal,twoside]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts,mathtools}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eqnarray}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow,array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\graphicspath{{Figs/}}
\newcommand{\mi}{\mathrm{i}} 
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{\arg\!\min}
\usepackage{relsize}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{$\mathbf{Theorem}$}
\newtheorem{lem}{$\mathbf{Lemma}$}
\newtheorem{cor}{$\mathbf{corollary}$}
\newtheorem{prop}{$\mathbf{Proposition}$}
\newtheorem{disc}{$\mathbf{Discussion}$}
\newtheorem{exmp}{$\mathbf{Example}$}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{$\mathbf{Definition}$}
\newtheorem{note}{$\mathbf{Note}$}
\newtheorem{remk}{$\mathbf{Remark}$}
\usepackage[scr = dutchcal]{mathalfa}

% ==================
%\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}

\begin{document}

    \begin{note}
        something
    \end{note}



\end{document}
```

Comment: `$\mathbf{Theorem}$`? Are you trying to override what `IEEEtran` prescribes? That's a “don't-do-it”, your submission will possibly be rejected.

Comment: The code raises errors.

Comment: I think we could define how the theorem show in the text.

Comment: @Amin A suggestion for your code: `\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts,mathtools}`. There are two amsthm. After amssymb contains amsfonts and mathtools is a robust package than amsmath that works better than amsmath.

Comment: I get **Note 1.** in bold face. What's the problem? Of course it would be boldface also with `\newtheorem{note}{Note}`.

Comment: @egreg: if you check simply by putting the $\mathbf{Note~1}$ inside the text, I think the number has a minor difference with the current status.

Comment: @Amin You can clearly see that “Note” is typeset in the math bold font which is *not* the same as the text bold font. If you add the `compsoc` option to the document class, you'll see the same fonts. Using `$\mathbf{Note}$` for this is as wrong as it could be.